# Unexpected result in an efficiency experiment between python lists vs numpy arrays

Tags: python, list, numpy-ndarray

I'm doing some experiments in order to compare the efficiency of python lists and numpy arrays. Afaik, numpy arrays are more efficient than lists. However, the following code gives surprising results.

```
import numpy as np
import time

length = 1000000
a = np.random.rand(length)

l = []


tic = time.time()
for i in range(length):
  a[i] = np.random.rand()
toc = time.time()

print("Numpy array: "+str(1000*(toc-tic))+"ms")

tic = time.time()
for i in range(length):
  l.append(np.random.rand())
toc = time.time()

print("List: "+str(1000*(toc-tic))+"ms")
```

The following is printed:

```
Numpy array: 618.1871891021729ms
List: 524.2352485656738ms
```

I did not expect this results. I thought that appending to lists should not be as efficient as iterating over numpy arrays. But the result is the opposite. Can you give an explanation of these results.

Comment: @sj95126 The array is created before the timing begins. In list test, yes, resizing is involved and that is why I expect a longer time.

Comment: The array of numpy is good at batch operations, such as adding the same value to each element in the array, rather than operating element by element.

Comment: The List operation creates a list of random numbers but so does a = np.random.rand(length) and it does this in a few msecs, which shows the efficiency of Numpy and how it should be used. There is no point in creating a Numpy array and then iterating over it one element at a time using a Python loop.